# how to change position of div element

Tags: html

I have a div element

```
<div id="divKPI" class="divKPI" >
    <asp:Label ID="lblKPI" runat="server" CssClass="lblKPI"></asp:Label>
    </div>
```

I have the class

```
.divKPI
{
    padding-top:800;
    text-align:center;
}
```

It is setting the label to center but not positioning the label element.Please help me.I have also used "top" but of no use

Answer (score 0):

```
#lblKPI {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: xxx px;
}
```

Comment: :I tried it.But still the same.Not positioning the lable element.

Comment: You have to set a fixed width.

Comment: I tried this also but still not changing the position of label element